# Expanding shell variable references in a HTML file

Tags: html, shell

`script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
var1="CAT"
var2="sucks"
```

`table.html`:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
   <td> var1 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> var2 </td>
</tr>
</table>
The variables from script are var1 and var2</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have `script.sh` that has 2 variables; `var1` and `var2`. And I have a separate `table.html` file. Now I want the values of `var1` and `var2` in the HTML table.

And I want that when the script runs I should get table in the mail.

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: i have written the script and html table tags.
this is just an example of what i want.
when i should run the script a mail should come in form of HTML table

Comment: Please see this info: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: my question perfectly correct. I need an html report generated by running the script and it should come as a table in mail. You can ignore table. I want the values from script to html. my question is very clear but if you haven't worked on this so it might be the case like you are not aware of it.

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: i am already done with script and html table just need syntax for exporting variable from my script to html. not even asking for code..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351076/linux-bash-and-html-variables-import-and-export get reference

Comment: The question you link to seems to contain the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you could do:

- Use some convention for burying shell variable names in your HTML - say, `__shell_var__` instead of just `shell_var`.  This will make it easy to identify the shell variables and prevent any other strings from being replaced.
- Run the following code that does the substitution for you in one go:

---

```
# assumes shell variables are enclosed between __ and __
perl -lpe 's/__(.+?)__/$ENV{$1}/g' html_file > html_file_transformed
```

---

See this related post: [Replace a part of a string with a shell variable's expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41598662/replace-a-part-of-a-string-with-a-shell-variables-expansion/41599816#41599816)